# AWS S3 Pre-signed url for client side encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am using Client side encryption with KMS for S3 objects and using `AmazonS3EncryptionClient` for storing and fetching objects. This internally generates Data Encryption Keys and stores them alongside the S3 objects in the metadata.

Now I want to generate Pre-Signed URLs which remain active for ~10 min for public access. `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` is able to create urls when the object is encrypted using Server Side Encryption.

Is there a way to generate these URLs for Client side encrypted objects using `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`? If not, are there other patterns using Lambda or other services?